# How is this component being rendered?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to implement a react component in Vue, but I first need to make sure I understand how this component works. I can infer that:

1. A `<DirectedEdge/>` element is rendered for each object in the `edges` prop **if** the value of the time prop is between the edge object's `data.timerange` property and **if** an object exists in the `vertices` prop with a key matching the first value of the edge object's own key (an array string).
2. A `<Vertice/>` is rendered for each object in the `vertices` prop **if** the first value of the object's `data.times` property is less than or equal to the value of the `time` prop.

```
    import { Svg } from './styles'
    import DirectedEdge from './directed-edge'
    import Vertice from './vertice'
    
    type Props = {
      time: number
      vertices: object
      edges: object
      bottomRight: array
    }
    
    // render the graph at a given time (time)
    const Graph = ({ time, edges, vertices, bottomRight }: Props) => {
      return (
        <Svg viewBox={`0 0 ${bottomRight[0]} ${bottomRight[1]}`}>
          {Object.entries(edges).map(([key, data]) => {
            const [u, v] = JSON.parse(key)
    
            return (
              time >= data.timeRange[0] &&
              time <= data.timeRange[1] &&
              vertices[u]?.coord &&
              vertices[v]?.coord && (
                <DirectedEdge
                  key={key}
                  start={vertices[u].coord}
                  end={vertices[v].coord}
                  label={data.label}
                />
              )
            )
          })}
          {Object.entries(vertices).map(([key, data]) => {
            return (
              time >= data.times[0] && (
                <Vertice
                  key={key}
                  center={data.coord}
                  label={data.label}
                />
              )
            )
          })}
        </Svg>
      )
    }
    
    export default Graph
```

my edges prop data:

```
edges: {
"[0,10]": { label: 1, timeRange: [ 37, 54 ] },
​​
"[0,1]": { label: 2,  timeRange: [ 1, 34 ] }
}
```

vertices prop data:

```
vertices: {
    ​ coord: [ 368.75, 50 ] ​​,
     label: "5" ​​​,
     memoized: false ​​,
     times:[ 0, 36, 56 ]
    }
```

Is my interpretation of this component correct?

What am I missing?

Comment: By the way, vertices is the plural of vertex, not "vertice" :)

Comment: `timeRange` defines an interval `from-to`. An edge is rendered if the `time` is inside the interval. A vertex is rendered if the time is bigger than the first element in `times`.

Comment: Returning `false` from a component means nothing will be rendered, so you just need to understand the logic in the if statement, which isn't related to react.

Comment: You seem to understand the logic just fine. Do you want to ask something specific about this logic?

Comment: @AlexWayne yes actually I want to understand how to implement the same functionality in Vue but I just wanted to make sure I understood what the react code did first